# How many N by N adjacency matrices exist with maximum degree of m?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I want to calculate the number of adjacency matrices corresponding to graphs with $N$ nodes satisfying **all** of the following properties:

1. There are no isolated nodes (each row of the matrix must have at least one 1).
2. The maximum degree for each node is at most $m \leq N$ (For example, if $m=3$, then each row of the matrix can have at most three 1s).
3. The adjacency matrix represents an undirected graph.

**My attempts thus far**: I know that the number of adjacency matrices for an undirected graph with $N$ nodes is $2^{N(N-1)/2}$, but I have not been able to incorporate the remaining assumptions.

Comment: It seems like you've already answered (3). The undirected case is $2^{N(N-1)/2}$ while the directed case is $2^{N(N-1)}$. I also don't see how (4) constrains the problem at all; "not necessarily connected" means "connected or not connected", which can be anything.

Comment: @parsiad I don't think they are separate problems - I thought the question was to find the number of graphs with all of the properties simultaneously.

Comment: Thak you @parsiad for the response. $2^{\frac{N(N-1)}{2}}$ is for the case that has no constraint on the number of edges for the graph, i.e., the adjacency matrix might have $0,1,..., N-1$ number of 1s at each row. However, I want to count the number of possible adjacency matrices (or even find an upper bound for it) that have at most a limited number of 1s at each row. Also, you are right about the property $(4)$. It is not a constraint.

Comment: @JairTaylor: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: FWIW, the closest I can find in OEIS is [A263293](//oeis.org/A263293) for unlabelled graphs, but you're asking about labelled graphs. This gives you a lower bound, and you can multiply by $n!$ for an upper bound (which is probably a reasonable first order approximation, since most graphs have trivial automorphism groups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is an incomplete solution, and I would like to come back to this when I have time.
>   Hopefully you can take this as a starting point and run with it.
>   Note that if you just want an approximation, you can use the [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method).
>   Let me know if this interests you and I can expand.

**Assumption**. $0 \leq n \leq m < N$ are integers.

Let's start with a simple version of your problem in which we drop the requirement of undirectedness.

Let $g(i) \equiv {}_{N-1} C_i \cdot  {}_2F_1(1, i - N + 1; i + 1; -1)$ where ${}_a C_b$ is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) and ${}_2F_1{}$ is the [ordinary hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

**Lemma (Counting digraphs)**.
There are exactly $(g(n) - g(m+1))^N$ *directed* graphs with
(*i*)   $N$ nodes,
(*ii*)  $n \leq \operatorname{outdeg}(v) \leq m$, and
(*iii*) no self-loops (i.e., no edges of the form $v \rightarrow v$).

By symmetry, the above also holds if we replace $\operatorname{outdeg}$ with $\operatorname{indeg}$.

*Proof*.
There are ${}_{N-1} C_k$ ways to assign $k$ edges to a *single* node if we exclude self-loops.
It follows that there are $\sum_{k = n}^m {}_{N-1} C_k = \sum_{k = 0}^m {}_{N-1} C_k - \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} {}_{N-1} C_k$ ways to assign edges to a *single* node.
Some tedious algebra reveals that $\sum_{k = 0}^{\ell-1} {}_{N-1} C_k = 2^{N-1} - g(\ell)$, from which the result follows.

*Figure*. $\log$ of the number of digraphs when $n = 0$ (values $m \geq N$ are capped to $N - 1$).

[image: Log of the number of digraphs with varying maximum out-degree]

Let's return to your original problem.
This problem is much harder because unlike the simpler problem above, one cannot "uncouple" the nodes of the graph to obtain an expression of the form $(\cdot)^N$.

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the nonnegative integers.
When $k$ is a positive integer, let $\mathbb{N}^k$ denote the usual Cartesian product.
For convenience, let $A^0 \equiv \{ 0 \}$ for any set $A$.
Let $\mathbf{x}_{(-1)} \equiv (x_2, \ldots, x_N)$ denote the vector $\mathbf{x}$ with its first co-ordinate removed.
When $\mathbf{x} \equiv (x_1)$ is a singleton vector, we interpret this as $\mathbf{x}_{(-1)} \equiv 0$.

Let $u_0(0) = 1$.
For each positive integer $k \leq N$, let $u_k : \mathbb{N}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by 
$$
u_k(\mathbf{x}) =
\sum_{\mathbf{y} \in \mathcal{Y}} u_{k-1}(\mathbf{x}_{(-1)} + \mathbf{y})
\qquad \text{where} \qquad
\mathcal{Y} \equiv \left \{
  \mathbf{y} \in \{0,1\}^{k-1}
  \colon n \leq x_1 + \mathbf{1} \cdot \mathbf{y} \leq m
\right \}.
$$

**Lemma (Counting undirected graphs)**. There are exactly $u_N(\mathbf{0})$ *undirected* graphs satisfying the same properties (*i*), (*ii*), and (*iii*) as above.

Code implementing the recurrence is given at the end of this post.
Note, however, that this code only has a slight edge over the naive $O(2^{N^2})$ algorithm involving enumerating all possibilities.

*Figure*. $\log$ of the number of undirected graphs when $n = 0$.

[image]

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

_cache = {}

def log_num_undirected_graphs(num_nodes, min_out_degree, max_out_degree):

    def u(x):
        k = len(x)
        if k == 0: return 1
        key = (min_out_degree, max_out_degree) + x
        result = _cache.get(key, None)
        if result is not None: return result
        result = 0
        Y = itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=k-1) if k > 1 else [()]
        for y in Y:
            tmp = x[0] + sum(y)
            if tmp < min_out_degree or tmp > max_out_degree: continue
            x_prime = tuple(x_i + y_i for x_i, y_i in zip(x[1:], y))
            result += u(x_prime)
        _cache[key] = result
        return result

    zero = (0,) * num_nodes
    return np.log(u(zero))
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much, @parsiad.

Comment: @m3359s: I'm glad it was helpful to you, but as I said, it's only a partial answer. I would like to give anybody (myself included) a chance to provide a more efficient answer, so feel free to un-accept for the time being (up to you).

Comment: @m3359s: Added some code and another plot.

Comment: @m3359s: It seems like this question hasn't received any further attention. At this point, you may consider putting a bounty on it (by spending your reputation) or accept my partial answer.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have enough reputation to put a bounty on my question :) For the time being, I'm going to accept your answer @parsiad.